# How to increase space between contact information in moderncv?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, moderncv

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,legalpaper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{10pt}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{FirstName}{LastName}
\phone[mobile]{+1 (111) 111-1111}                   
\email{firstname@gmail.com}    
\social{https://www.linkedin.com/in/firstname/}
\homepage{firstname.github.io}         

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

How can I increase the vertical space between the contact information rendering on the right hand side?